# Omnifaces TagAttribute Id cannot be used as id

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I have the following Facelet Taglib:

```
<ui:composition
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <o:tagAttribute name="id"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="#{id}" layout="block" styleClass="idTest">
        #{id}
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

The taglib.xml looks like this:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>idTest</tag-name>
    <source>resources/myProject/tags/idTest.xhtml</source>
</tag>
```

And the code, where it is used is simply:

```
<myProject:idTest/>
```

How can it be, that the following HTML is being rendered:

```
<div class="idTest">
    j_ido489794984_4bf870cd
</div>
```

Why does my `PanelGroup` have no `id`? The `id` is generated like it is expected based on the documentation of [`o:tagAttribute`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/tagAttribute), since the content of the `div` is rendered. But as `id` it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed confusing.

The [documentation](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/tagAttribute) literally says:

> *... it will autogenerate an unique ID in the form of `j_ido[tagId]` where `[tagId]` is the `<o:tagAttribute>` tag's own unique ID.*

But the actual behavior is more like so:

> *... it will override any autogenerated ID into the form of `j_ido[tagId]` where `[tagId]` is the `<o:tagAttribute>` tag's own unique ID.*

In other words, when JSF itself **needs** to render the `id` attribute of a HTML element, usually because it's required by some internal logic further down in the chain, such as `<f:ajax>` and friends, and there is no explicit ID specified on the tag like so `<x:someTag id="fixedId" />`, then JSF will by default autogenerate one in the form of `j_id[autoIncrementInteger]`. But this will go wrong on tagfiles because the `autoIncrementInteger` may get bumped further by one on each postback depending on the JSF impl and view state configuration used. The `<o:tagAttribute>` simply attempts to ensure this way that the autogenerated ID stays the same on each postback.

When you edit your test tagfile to add `<f:ajax>`,

```xml
<h:panelGroup id="#{id}" layout="block" styleClass="idTest">
    <f:ajax event="click" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

then you'll see that the generated `<div>` has an `id`, because this is technically required by `<f:ajax>`.

```xml
<div id="j_ido-1512689859_13a7e7e3" class="idTest"
    onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'click',0,0)">
</div>
```

Or when you swap `<h:panelGroup>` for e.g. a `<h:form>` or whatever component which always requires an ID in the client side,

```xml
<h:form id="#{id}" styleClass="idTest">
    <ui:insert />
</h:form>
```

then you'll also see that it's generated.

```xml
<form id="j_ido-1512689859_13a7e7e3" name="j_ido-1512689859_13a7e7e3" method="post" action="/test.xhtml" class="idTest" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="j_ido-1512689859_13a7e7e3" value="j_ido-1512689859_13a7e7e3" />
    ...
</form>
```

In other words, the feature is working fine, but it was simply not used in your specific case because JSF didn't consider it necessary to generate it.

I've in the meanwhile [updated](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/a77b2c338cb9d5c1d715458885ee9836e6ea8dd1) the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How could I trick out JSF to generate an id for my div without f:ajax? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why do you want an ID which is apparently not going to be used anywhere?